# Direction of friction on particle placed on a rotating turntable

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction

If a particle is placed on a rotating turntable then the particle has a tendency to slip tangentially with respect to the underneath surface... So the friction should act tangentially to the particle... Why then does it act towards the center... Please explain with respect to inertial frame

Friction opposes relative slipping between surfaces... When the particle is initially placed on the rotating turntable... the surface under it has a tangential velocity. So, in order to oppose this slipping friction must act tangentially... How then does it act radially inward?

Comment: "so the friction should act tangentially to the particle" Force is proportional to the acceleration, not to the speed. And acceleration in general is not tangent to the trajectory.

Answer (score 8):

This shows the motion of the particle and turntable at an instant in time. We assume that the system has settled down i.e. at the instant shown the particle is moving at the same velocity as the bit of the turntable immediately underneath it.

[image: Turntable]

The particle's velocity is tangential to the turntable - I've indicated this by the dotted line. Because the turntable is rotating, the point on the turntable immediately under the particle is accelerating towards the centre at $a = r\omega^2$ where $r$ is the radius of the turntable and $\omega$ is the angular velocity.

If there were no friction the particle would travel in a straight line (along the dotted line) at constant velocity and we'd see the particle fly off the turntable.

If instead we see the particle stay in place on the turntable, there must be a force accelerating it, and that force must act in the direction of the acceleration i.e. towards the centre of the turntable. That force is of course the friction between the particle and the turntable, so the friction acts towards the centre of the turntable.

**Update:** Tanya asks what happens when a stationary particle is placed on the turntable.

[image: Turntable2]

The particle is placed on the turntable where the black dot is. At this instant the particle is stationary with the turntable skidding underneath it. The frictional force acts in the direction of the relative velocity between the particle and turntable, so at this moment the frictional force is tangential.

The particle accelerates in response to the frictional force, so some very short time later it has moved to the position shown by the open circle. I'm assuming the time is short enough that we can assume the particle has moved in a straight line: I've exaggerated the particle motion on the diagram to make the argument clearer.

Anyhow, because the particle has moved in a direction tangential to the turntable the direction of the relative velocity between the particle and turntable has changed. That means there is now a component of the frictional force downwards as well as in the original direction. The result is that the particle is now accelerated downwards as well as to the right. If you watched the particle it would follow a spiral centred on the centre of the turntable until it reached the edge and flew off or came to rest relative to the turntable. In either case the net result is that there has been an acceleration towards the centre of the turntable i.e. there is a component of the fictional force acting towards the centre.

Comment: Friction opposes relative slipping between surfaces...when the particle is initially placed on the rotating turntable ..the surface under it has a tangential velocity ...so in order to oppose this slipping friction must act tangentially...how then does it act radially inward ??

Comment: Thank u so much...  "If you watched the particle it would follow a spiral centred on the centre of the turntable until it reached the edge and flew off". Please Can u elaborate it ?

Comment: Have a look at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ParticleMovingOnARotatingDisk/ (you'll need to click the link to install the Wolfram CDF player).

Comment: Thank you very much John Rennie...You have very nicely explained the concept.

Comment: @JohnRennie Dropping the particle is equivalent to start the turntable from rest with the particle on it right?Lets assume that the particle is not in the edge of the turntable.  So at time $t=0$ we have friction in the direction of the tangential velocity. Why we don't have also friction perpendicular to the tangential if there is tendency between point and the particle to move relative?

Comment: @JohnRennie, you've said "That force is of course the friction between the particle and the turntable, so the friction acts towards the centre of the turntable" and "there has been an acceleration towards the centre..." I agree with this analysis, but you've used empirical evidence to explain the direction of the static friction force. I think the question is asking for a principle that would allow us to predict the direction of the static friction force without knowing in advance what the motion would look like.

Comment: @JohnRennie, as you've explained really well, if there were no friction, and we watched while standing on the floor, then we would see the particle move in an arc [like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Corioliskraftanimation.gif). But in the particle's frame, it moves radially outward. So is this a correct articulation of the rule: static friction on an object opposes the direction of sliding/slipping *as viewed from the object's frame of reference*? Or could we put it this way: static friction on an object is the equilibrant in the object's frame of reference?